# how to get heap start address of a elf binary

Tags: c, heap-memory, elf

I have written a sample program in C that uses libelf to dump the different sections.
However i want to dump the heap & stack segment starting address which is only available when the process is "live" (running).

This is what i do for a binary i read from disk.

```
elf_fd = open(elf_fname, O_RDWR);
    if(elf_fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open \"%s\" reason=%s\n", elf_fname, strerror(errno));
        return -1;;
    }

followed by

        if(elf_version(EV_CURRENT) == EV_NONE) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize libelf\n");
            res = -1;
            goto done;
        }
    
elf->e = elf_begin(elf->fd, ELF_C_READ, NULL);
if(!elf->e) {
    int err = elf_errno();
    if (err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open ELF file code=%d reason=%s\n", err, 
        elf_errmsg(err));
    }
    res = -1;
    goto done;
}
```

This works fine when i read the binary image on disk

For run time what i tried is instead of doing this
That is using the elf_fd returned by open

```
elf_fd = open(elf_fname, O_RDWR);
if(elf_fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open \"%s\" reason=%s\n", elf_fname, strerror(errno));
    return -1;;
}

I instead do this
That is i get a handle from the pid of the current process

elf_fd = pidfd_open(getpid(), 0);
if (elf_fd == -1) {
    perror("pidfd_open");
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to open self %d\n", elf_fd);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

It returns me a valid descriptor but when i use this descriptor with

```
elf->e = elf_begin(elf->fd, ELF_C_READ, NULL);
if(!elf->e) {
    int err = elf_errno();
    if (err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open ELF file code=%d reason=%s\n", err, 
        elf_errmsg(err));
     }
}
```

It says "Invalid descriptor".

Question is how can i get heap & stack base address of a live process from within it

Also yes i did also try at the very start in main call
sbrk(0) & that seems to print the heap start address but this may not always be reliable as there maybe no heap without a malloc call prior
for now it does seem to print it.

Comment: See [`pidfd_open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_open.2.html). It does not give you a file descriptor for a "live" ELF file. The addresses you are looking for can be found in [`/proc/[pid]/maps`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question is how can i get heap & stack base address of a live process from within it

Note that neither heap, nor stack have *anything* to do with the ELF format, or `libelf`.

There is *no such thing* as "heap base address" -- most modern heap allocators will perform *multiple* `mmap` calls to obtain memory from the OS, then "dole" it out to various `malloc` requests.

> i did also try at the very start in main call `sbrk(0)`

"Legacy" `malloc` used to obtain memory using `sbrk()`, but few modern ones do. If the malloc you are using does use `sbrk`, then calling `sbrk(0)` near the start of `main` is a usable approximation.

For the main thread stack, you would want to do the same. A good first approximation is taking `&argc`, and rounding it up to page boundary.

If you want to get better approximation, you could use the fact that on Linux (and possibly other ELF platforms) the kernel puts [specific values](https://lwn.net/Articles/519085/) on the stack before invoking the entry point. Iterating through the `__environ` values looking for the highest address will give a better approximation.

Comment: Great answer Thx

Comment: *"Legacy" `malloc` used to obtain memory using `sbrk()`, but few modern ones do.*  I'd put it a bit differently: modern implementations don't limit themselves to using only `sbrk()`.

Comment: Yes i agree as mine is a Ubuntu 20.04 with glibc 2.31 which is pretty recent version.